# Illustrator Cs4 Align Multiple Items To Multiple Artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, artboard

This question seems like it must've been asked already, but I can't find it.

In Illustrator CS4, imagine I have 16 artboards, each with a GroupItem/PathItem placed on them.  None of them are aligned.  I would like to select all objects, and then align each object relative to it's respective artboard.  Like - align to artboard, but each one is getting aligned to a different artboard.

Short of writing a script, I can't see a way to do this, but it seems like a thing that Adobe would've included this.

Any help?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without scripting